# Prove Isometry of a Translation

Tags: geometry

How do you use the distance formula to show that a translation is an isometry.

Specifically, The given equation is T(x,y)=(-y,x)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202837/proving-isometry-of-two-line-segments  From here you toke the comment and post is as another question??

Answer (score 1):

We have to show:

$$|T(x_1,y_1) - T(x_2,y_2)| = |(x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2)|$$

Now, $$|T(x_1,y_1) - T(x_2,y_2)| =|(-y_1,x_1) - (-y_2,x_2)| = \\ \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 +(y_1-y_2)^2} = |(x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2)|$$